# avconv - Extract one video frame and repeat it

Tags: avconv

I'd like to repeat one frame from a source video to output. I've tried the following

```
avconv -ss 00:20:00 -i INPUT_VIDEO -t 0.5 -vsync 1 -an -r 1 -vcodec libx264 VIDEO_1F
avconv -i VIDEO_1F -t 10 -r 1 -vcodec libx264 OUTPUT_VIDEO
```

But I found that `-ss` doesn't work in the former command, and it would always extract the first frame of input video; in the latter `-t` has no effects and the duration of the output video will be 2 seconds.

Any suggestion? Or, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

I've got a way out, with also 2 steps.

First extract the frame

```
avconv -ss 00:20:00 -i INPUT_VIDEO -vsync 1 -t 0.01 output.png
```

There is a chance that `avconv` extracts more than one frame within 0.01s, and terminates with an error "... Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'output.png' ...". But don't mind since we need only the first frame.

Then convert the image to video

```
avconv -loop 1 -i output.png -vcodec libx264 -tune stillimage -t 10 OUTPUT_VIDEO
```